# gawk/sed: find a line and replace the 3rd column

Tags: unix, sed, gawk

I have a file:

```
rs4648841   chr1    2365885 --  A   T   0.40095 0.228978043022122   chr1:2523811
rs4648843   chr1    2366316 --  T   C   0.15694 0.5736208829426915  chr1:2523811
rs61763906  chr1    2366517 --  A   G   0.07726 0.5566728930776897  chr1:2523811
```

I need to find a "rs4648843" in the first column and once I found a line containing it I want to edit a 4th column in this line to "ADS" (using sed, gawk doesn't matter)

tried: (but of course it did not work)

```
sed '/rs4648843/p' input | sed 's//ADD/g'
```

**EDIT:**
I need no new file to be created, I want to edit a file I have already.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, just to clarify, since `rs12123` never occurs in the first column in your sample input, you want nothing changed in the corresponding sample output?

Comment: wrt `EDIT: I need no new file to be created, I want to edit a file I have already.` - that is not possible with sed or awk and is extraordinarily difficult to accomplish in UNIX (hint: you need to use `dd`). Why is that a requirement?

Comment: @EdMorton, `ed` can edit files programmatically without creating temp files.

Comment: Hmm, well, yeah, kinda. `ed` uses a buffer which is the size of the original file so it's no different than using a temp file. It's like reading the whole input file into an array in awk, then closing the input file, and then processing the array writing the contents back to the original file. Yeah you can do it but it doesn't save you any memory or have any other benefits over a tmp file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '/^rs4648843/ {$4="ADS"}1' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
rs4648841   chr1  2365885  --   A  T  0.40095  0.228978043022122   chr1:2523811
rs4648843   chr1  2366316  ADS  T  C  0.15694  0.5736208829426915  chr1:2523811
rs61763906  chr1  2366517  --   A  G  0.07726  0.5566728930776897  chr1:2523811
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

Assuming that your input file is tab-separated:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=="rs4648843"{$4="ADS"} 1' file
rs4648841       chr1    2365885 --      A       T       0.40095 0.228978043022122       chr1:2523811
rs4648843       chr1    2366316 ADS     T       C       0.15694 0.5736208829426915      chr1:2523811
rs61763906      chr1    2366517 --      A       G       0.07726 0.5566728930776897      chr1:2523811
```

To change the existing file:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=="rs4648843"{$4="ADS"} 1' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

#### Using sed

Again, assuming tab-separated input, to change the file in-place:

```
sed -i -r '/^rs4648843/ {s/(([^\t]*\t){3})[^\t]+/\1ADS/}' file
```

The above was test on GNU sed.  For OSX (BSD) sed, try:

```
sed -i .bak -E '/^rs4648843/ {s/(([^\t]*\t){3})[^\t]+/\1ADS/;}' file
```

#### Using awk but passing in the `rs...` value as a variable

```
awk -v rs="rs4648843" -v OFS="\t" '$1==rs{$4="ADS"} 1' file
```

#### Using sed With a String With a Slash

As per the comments, suppose that, instead of `ADS`, we want to substitute in `TRAF6-RAG1/2`.  Since this contains a `/` character, it will confuse the `sed` command given above.  There are two possible solutions: one is to escape the `/` with a backslash.  This works as follows:

```
sed -r '/^rs4648843/ {s/(([^\t]*\t){3})[^\t]+/\1TRAF6-RAG1\/2/}' file
```

The other solution is to use a different marker for the substitution command.  sed's substitution commands are often written in the form `s/old/new/` but other markers besides `/` are possible.   As an example, the following use a vertical bar, `|`, as the marker instead of `/`, and thus accommodates the new string:

```
sed -r '/^rs4648843/ {s|(([^\t]*\t){3})[^\t]+|\1TRAF6-RAG1/2|}' file
```

Comment: It is possible to pass "rs4648843" to awk as a variable? I am programing in ruby and I have an array consisting of "rs222",... and I need to pass each variable to awk

Comment: @Tonja OK.  I added a version that uses awk's `-v` option to pass in the `rs...` value as a variable.

Comment: it seems that sed for GNU throws an error if I have instead of "ADS" a "TRAF6-RAG1/2"

Comment: @Tonja I updated the answer with two solutions for that.  The problem is that, with sed, one has to be careful anytime one of the substitution strings has a sed-active character which, in that case, is the slash: `/`.

Comment: @Tonja why are you calling awk from Ruby? Doesn't Ruby have it's own language/functionality for manipulating text?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is, as it appears to be, fixed width:

```
gawk -v item=rs4648843 '
    BEGIN {
        FIELDWIDTHS="12 8 8 4 4 4 8 20 12"
        OFS=""
        pattern = "^"item"\\\>" 
    }
    $1 ~ pattern {$4 = sprintf("%-4s", "ADS")} 
    1
' file
```

```
rs4648841   chr1    2365885 --  A   T   0.40095 0.228978043022122   chr1:2523811
rs4648843   chr1    2366316 ADS T   C   0.15694 0.5736208829426915  chr1:2523811
rs61763906  chr1    2366517 --  A   G   0.07726 0.5566728930776897  chr1:2523811
```

---

To edit the file in-place, we can fall back on `ed`:

```
rs="rs4648843"
ed file <<END_ED
g/^$rs\>/ s/^\(\([^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+\)\{3\}\)[^[:blank:]]\+/\1ADS/
w
q
END_ED
```

The lengthy regular expression captures the first 3 whitespace-separated words, and replaces the 4th with "ADS"